# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method get_Item(Int32)' method

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two tables and one  temporary table. In the two tables I have records which I join based on the fact if the name of the record is the same. The join is successfull. I am taking the id's from the both tables and putting it in temporary table with the name. So the temporary table have 3columns : idfromoldtable, idfromnewtable and name. So after that I am creating another table which needs to store only the idfromthenewdb and the name, but the following error ,which is in the header of the topic, occurs when the consoleApp executes.

```
var queryMapping = from tempRecords in newDb.temporaryTables
                   where tempRecords.tableName == "Settlements"
                   select tempRecords;

for (int i = 0; i < listHospital.Count; i++)
{
    var mappingItem = queryMapping.First(item => item.idFromOldDb == (int)listHospital[i].SettlementId); //this is the line where the error shows
    listHospital[i].SettlementId = mappingItem.idFromNewDb;
}
```

Any suggestions how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Does ToListing() the queryMapping solve the problem?

Comment: @BadDub nope, it doesn't solve the problem. Look the answer below which Ehsan Sajjad gave. :)

Comment: I thought moving the queryMapping into memory (tolisting) would have recognised the int cast as it no longer calls the db with an int cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq to Entities does not know how to translate the int cast code in to sql, you need to cast it outside the linq query and then use the value in the query, a quick fix for this will be like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listHospital.Count; i++)
{
      int settlmentId = (int)listHospital[i].SettlementId;
      var mappingItem = queryMapping.First(item => item.idFromOldDb == settlmentId );
      listHospital[i].SettlementId = mappingItem.idFromNewDb;
}
```

Comment: This was the problem ! Thanks a lot ! So if we are using Linq to Entities and we have a cast.We need always to to cast it outside the linq query and after that use the variable?

Comment: You can only write the code in linq query that can be translated to the relevant sql,

Comment: isn't this Linq to SQL (since the operation is only executing when First() is called)?  if it was LINQ to entities there shouldn't be a problem!  || also - this query is sent to the DB for every iteration of the for loop - which might cause problems